# google map API: unable display map

Tags: jquery

it display do you want to share your location in url but wont display the map. So I wonder where can be go wrong? But it show on IE and firefox but not showing on safari and chrome

```
$(document).ready(function(){
initialize();
$("#btInit").click(function(){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);  
}); //call this function when the user click
});

var map;
```

//MAP

```
function initialize() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
 var mapOptions = {
zoom: 17
};
}
```

//GEOLOCATION

```
function onSuccess(position){  
   var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
   var myLong = position.coords.longitude;
   var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong);

    map.setCenter(latLng);


google.maps.event.addDomListener(document, initialize);
```

Comment: i thing you should have to follow this link
http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-use-geolocation-api-with-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the scope. I fixed it like so (jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gjacobs/D9ug8/1/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // Ask for permission
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
        var myLong = position.coords.longitude;
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong);
        map.setCenter(latLng);
    }); 

    var map;
    var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688, -74.004142);
    var options = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: centerPosition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], options);
});
```

But there are also other options, that give you cleaner JavaScript.

Comment: it is showing on firefox and ie but it not showing on chrome and safari